# shutdown threads using managedexecutorservice after stipulated time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, ejb, executorservice

I have a list of threads that need to be executed simultaneously. I was doing this using executorservice initially. The threads that need to be executed are coming from DB and I am retrieving their classnames, storing them in vendorDetails list.

```
for (Object vendorThread : vendorDetails) {
            String thread = (String) vendorThread;
            //timeout = details.getTimeout();
            Runnable worker = null;
            try {
                Class c = Class.forName(thread);
                Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor(SearchRequest.class, Results.class);
                worker = (Runnable) cons.newInstance(searchRequest, Results);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (worker == null) {
                System.out.println("------------------------ WORKER IS NULL ---------------");
            }
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
        try {
            if (!executor.isTerminated()) {
                executor.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //ex.fillInStackTrace(); 
        }
```

I want to achieve something similar in ejb so I am using `ManagedExecutorService`.

```
    @EJB
    private ThreadName1 threadName1 ;
    @EJB
    private ThreadName2 threadName2 ;    
for (Object vendorThread : vendorDetails) {
                System.out.println("in for loop");
                String thread = (String) vendorThread;
                System.out.println("thread:" + thread);
                //timeout = details.getTimeout();
                Runnable worker = null;
                try {
                    if (thread.equals("threadName1")) {
                        System.out.println("in if");
                        threadName1.setReqRes(SearchRequest, Results);
                        worker = (Runnable) threadName1;
                    } else if (thread.equals("threadName2")) {
                        System.out.println("in spice if");
                        threadName2.setReqRes(SearchRequest, Results);
                        worker = (Runnable) threadName2;
                    }
                    System.out.println("after if");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (worker == null) {
                    System.out.println("------------------------ WORKER IS NULL ---------------");
                }

                System.out.println("before execute");
                //managedExecutorService.execute(worker);
                managedExecutorService.submit(worker);
                System.out.println("after execute");
            }
            System.out.println("before shutdown");
            //managedExecutorService.shutdownNow();
            System.out.println("after shutdown");
            try {
                System.out.println("after shutdown");
                /*if (!managedExecutorService.isTerminated()) {
                    managedExecutorService.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }*/

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.fillInStackTrace();
                //  ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So ideally I want the threads to run for a stipulated time say 30secs and then return the results of whichever threads have completed their execution.
Now the problem is calling any threadlifecycle methods like shutdown etc throws an exception.
How do I achieve this?
I am using the default ManagedExecutorSerivce.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the right solution. But I am doing this for now as a workaround. Adding to a Future list all the tasks that are submitted. Then waiting for stipulated time and cancelling all the running tasks. I am sure there is a more elegant solution.

```
                    ArrayList<Future> taskList = new ArrayList<>();        
                    for (Object vendorThread : vendorDetails) {
                        System.out.println("in for loop");
                        String thread = (String) vendorThread;
                        System.out.println("thread:" + thread);
                        //timeout = details.getTimeout();
                        Runnable worker = null;
                        try {
                            if (thread.equals("threadName1")) {
                                System.out.println("in if");
                                threadName1.setReqRes(SearchRequest, Results);
                                worker = (Runnable) threadName1;
                            } else if (thread.equals("threadName2")) {
                                System.out.println("in spice if");
                                threadName2.setReqRes(SearchRequest, Results);
                                worker = (Runnable) threadName2;
                            }
                            System.out.println("after if");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (worker == null) {
                            System.out.println("------------------------ WORKER IS NULL ---------------");
                        }

                        System.out.println("before execute");
                        //managedExecutorService.execute(worker);
                        taskList.add(managedExecutorService.submit(worker));;
                        System.out.println("after execute");
                    }
                    System.out.println("before shutdown");
                    //managedExecutorService.shutdownNow();
                    System.out.println("after shutdown");
                    try {
                        System.out.println("after shutdown");
                        /*if (!managedExecutorService.isTerminated()) {
                            managedExecutorService.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        }*/
                System.out.println("before sleep");
                long startTimeLogon = System.currentTimeMillis();
                boolean allComplete;
                int trueCount = 0;
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("true count " + trueCount++);
                    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeLogon) >= timeout * 1000) {
                        break;
                    }
                    allComplete = true;
                    for (Future f : taskList) {                    
                        if (!f.isDone()) {
                            allComplete=false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(allComplete)
                        break;
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                }
                System.out.println("after sleep");
                for (Future f : taskList) {
                    if (!f.isDone()) {
                        f.cancel(true);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("after cancel");

                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.fillInStackTrace();
                        //  ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
```